# How to Play Multiple Streams with FFPLAY at the Same Time using RTSP Url

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp, live-streaming, rtsp-client

I am trying to play live stream coming from the server with RTSP URL. A sample RTSP URL is given below:

```
rtsp://username:password@machine_ip/42331536059e9f21
```

Actually, this stream is the call between two participants (caller & called). But when I play this URL with FFPLAY, I get just one stream(called) while I should get both streams (caller and called). I am using the following command:

```
ffplay rtsp://username:password@machine_ip/42331536059e9f21
```

Am I missing some parameters along with this command to fetch all streams.

Comment: With streams you mean RTSP tracks?

Comment: Actually, FFPLAY is unable to play both streams at the same time. How can we actually both streams with this?

Comment: Ah ok, I'm not an FFmpeg specialist but Googling seems to show that `-filter_complex amix` could help with this. But look at the FFmpeg documentation for more details on this filter.

Comment: okay, thanks for your interest. appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually the limitation of FFPLAY that it doesn't support multiple streams at the same time.

> FFplay has currently no support for playing two audio streams simultaneously.

[Here is the reference of this answer.](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5329#comment:2)

Comment: what about one video stream and one audio stream, how to combine them uisng ffplay ??????????